# Disable atom gutter line highlight

Tags: atom-editor, highlight, gutter

I would like to disable the gray highlight on top of the gutter in the atom text editor.

[image]

As can be seen, it is the gray box right before the cursor.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First, navigate to your custom stylesheet [as described in the Atom documentation](https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/#style-tweaks).

In the `styles.less` file that pops up, add the following:

```
atom-text-editor .gutter .line-number.cursor-line {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Save the file.